# How can I get rid of space in this <li> item? Its not padding or margin from what i can tell

Tags: html, css

I have some `<li>` items as part of my navigation bar on the website i'm making, I'm completely stumped on some spacing that occurs just before the items.

margin and padding are both 0, and list-style-type is set to none. Any ideas?

I forgot the [website link! Here.](http://www.holly.im/)
[image]

**Additional details as requested:**

- The text for the `<li>` items is actual text and not an image.
- The text for the `<li>` items is not aligned (removed superfluous
  'center' ).

**Related CSS:**

```
/*****************

NAVIGATION STYLING

*****************/
#navigation{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index:10;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
    #navigation a:link, a:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size:4.16em;
        margin: 0.5em;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        float: left;
        width:100%;
    }
    #navigation #me{

    }
    #navigation a.im:link, a.im:visited{
    line-height: 0em;
    }
    #navigation a.holly:link, a.holly:visited{
    line-height: 0em;
    }
    #navigation a.games_programmer:link, a.games_programmer:visited{
    line-height: 0em;
    }
    #navigation ul{
        height: 50px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background:#1d6482;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #navigation li{
        display: inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
```

Comment: We will need more information to figure this one out properly. Is it possible that the 'Portfolio' text is a background image that isn't positioned or that the LI has `text-align:right;` on it?

Comment: What good does text-align:center? And margin: 0.5em; is suspicios!

Comment: Why are you putting a left-floated A element inside a inline-block LI element? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have in the navigation that any link should have `margin: 0.5em`. That looks to be about the size of the space. It appears by your screenshot that you have it open in Chrome. You should be able to see all styles applied to that element and use the checkboxes on each to remove or even alter the applied styles to find the culprit.

Comment: You are correct. Holly was looking for `li`'s styles, while the problem lied in `li`'s children.